# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in

Tags: php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'category'" or die (mysql_error ());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc '($sql)')
{
echo '<li><a href="/">' .$row['name']. '</a></li>';
}
?>
```

где косяк?!

Comment: @denis062 уберите апострофы в строке **'($sql)'**

Comment: помоему, как говорится, тут и чёрт ногу сломал бы..

Comment: @denis062, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @denis062, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6):

1. Там где `mysql_fetch_assoc`, у вас лишние кавычки.
2. Функция `mysql_fetch_assoc` в качестве параметра принимает результат выполенения функции mysql_query. Вообщем должно быть как то так:

   ```
   <?php 
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM category';
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo '<li><a href="/">' . $row['name'] . '</a></li>';
   } 
   ?>
   ```

   Если вы только учитесь, то лучше учиться работать с правильными инструментами, погуглите php PDO.